# how to achieve this array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to be able to save an array (if possible), so that I can get to an entry within it quickly and easily with a unique identifier, something like:

array structure:

```
[
    1001:{loads of info},
    1002:{loads more info}
]
```

and to get values like:

```
var info_i_want = array.1001;
```

I have the 'loads of info' part already in a json object, just need to built this new array?
I ask because at the moment I have to loop through each object in the array to check if its the one I want before I can do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want you can use numeric keys with an object literal (not the array notation you used above):

```
var obj = {
    1001: { /* data */},
    1002: { /* data */}
};
```

With numeric keys, you must use bracket notation to dereference; i.e:

```
obj[1001]; // *not* dot reference `obj.1001` which will not work
```

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT**

For reference read the Object section of [Javascript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#object), specifically *Accessing Properties*

Answer (score 0):

you can assume like this.

```
var arr = [
    {1001: "loads of info"},
    {1002: "loads more info"}
]

var info_i_want = arr[0].1001 // returns loads of info
```

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot dereference a numeric key with dot notation - so the line `var info_i_want = arr[0].1001` will raise a `SyntaxError`.